# Pourquoi y a-t-il autant de voyelles en français ? / Why are there so many vowels in French?

Tags: phonétique, linguistique

Le français possède jusqu'à seize voyelles :

```
i, y, e, ɛ, ə, ø, œ, a, u, o, ɔ, ɑ, ɑ̃, ɔ̃, ɛ̃, œ̃
```

Le castillan n'en a que cinq :

```
i, e, a, u, o
```

L'italien que sept :

```
i, e, ɛ, a, u, o, ɔ
```

*et cætera*.

Ce sont pourtant des langues assez proches¹, d'où vient cette particularité du français ?

Question bonus : pendant qu'on y est, pourquoi aussi peu de consonnes ?

---

<sup>1. romanes. Notons que le breton par exemple en a jusqu'à quatorze.</sup>

---

French has up to 16 vowels:

```
i, y, e, ɛ, ə, ø, œ, a, u, o, ɔ, ɑ, ɑ̃, ɔ̃, ɛ̃, œ̃
```

Castillan only has 5. Italian has 7. Why does French have so many more vowels than its (linguistically) close neighbors?

Comment: D'ailleurs, pour la question bonus, nous sommes classés comme “average” : http://wals.info/feature/1A?tg_format=map&v1=c00d&v2=c99f&v3=cfff&v4=cf6f&v5=cd00 Pourvu que les agences de notation ne nous dégradent pas !

Comment: D'où viennent ces inventaires de voyelles? Par exemple pour l'italien, j'ai tendance a faire une différence entre le i de *Firenze* et celui de *aglio*. De plus, je ne suis pas certain que le français soit isolé dans les langues romanes: le portugais aussi a beaucoup de voyelles.

Comment: @mouviciel Je ne suis pas expert, mais il semble que ce sont des variantes du phonème /i/, je parle bien ici de phonèmes, pas de sons. Pour les sources, par exemple [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_language#Phonology) et [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_language#Phonology). Le portugais m'a l'air d'être une autre exception, j'ai vérifié pour le rumantsch, le catalan, le frioulan et le roumain, aucun ne passe les neuf voyelles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*(English summary below)*

La transformation qui a conduit le français à cette situation pourrait correspondre à ce qui est expliqué [sur Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_French#Internal_history).

Je pourrais l'écrire ici, mais c'est trop long. (Si tu penses que cela répond à ta question, n'hésite pas à l'écrire ici.) La page est en anglais, je n'ai pas pu trouver les mêmes informations dans la page en français.

*Note:* À propos de cette page, je ne suis pas très sûr : ta question n'est pas facile, et je pense que tu pourrais trouver de meilleures réponses sur Linguistics SE, mais, en tout cas, j'ai essayé de répondre à tes doutes.

J'espère que ça va t'aider.

---

**EDIT après ton commentaire**: Dans le [même article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_French#Internal_history), tu peux lire que le développement des voyelles antérieures arrondies `/y/`, `/ø/`, et `/œ/` peut être dû à des influences germaniques, parce que peu de langues romanes, autres que le Français, ont ces voyelles.

Mais j'ai trouvé quelques informations sur les origines et l'évolution dans « [Histoire de la langue : Du latin à l'ancien français.](http://books.google.it/books?id=QH08-kXq_Y8C) » par *Peter A. Machonis*, à la page 101 : « Origine de la voyelle [y] ».

Malheureusement, je pense qu'on parle seulement de la voyelle `/y/` et partiellement de la voyelle `/œ/`, pas de la voyelle `/ø/` (mais je n'ai pas lu tout le document, tu peux peut-être trouver quelque chose). Enfin, ce document parle aussi des consonnes, si tu es intéressé par leur évolution.

---

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_French#Internal_history) gives a possible explanation of the transformation that led to the large inventory of vowels in French. For example, a section explains how the anterior rounded vowels `/y/`, `/ø/` and `/œ/` may be due to Germanic influences, since Romance languages have these vowels.

I also found information about `/y/` and `/œ/` (but not `/ø/`) in *[Histoire de la langue : Du latin à l'ancien français.](http://books.google.it/books?id=QH08-kXq_Y8C)* by Peter A. Machonis, page 101 : “*Origine de la voyelle [y]*”.

Comment: Good article, and quite enlightening regarding some points. As far as I can guess after reading it, the singularities of French compared to other Romance languages essentially stem from a slower assimilation of Celtic languages and an enhanced contact with Germanic languages. Still, I would like more details on vowels. Especially on the presence of the front rounded series.

Comment: @Evpok: I found more material. There was not information for _all_ of those vowels, but luckily, it's going to give you some clue about it. Please note that in that document it mentions some theories (inside that paragraph I "linked"), it might be a good reference point for you. :) Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez: Merci. :) Mais, je me demande, pourquoi "**La transformation** qui a conduit le Français à cette situation pourrait correspondre à **ce qui est expliqué**", si «la transformation» est féminin?

Comment: Dans ce cas, « ce » est un pronom qui utilisé de façon très large et il peut désigner n'importe quoi (il est toujours masculin). Si tu voulais parler de « la transformation qui est expliquée… » (il semble que ce soit le cas), alors tu peux remplacer par « celle qui est expliquée ». Pardon si j'ai un peu changé le sens :-)

Comment: Le sens me semble le même, non? :D Je voulait savoir à propos du fait que on peut utiliser "ce" ou "celle", il n'importe pas...

Comment: Bonne [question](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) ! Peut-on utiliser indifféremment « ce qui » ou « celle qui » dans cette phrase: […] et pourquoi? ;-)

Comment: @Stéphane: [ici](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/915/peut-on-utiliser-ce-dans-cette-phrase) :)