# Peut-on utiliser « ce » dans cette phrase ?

Tags: pronoms, genre, démonstratifs

Dans les commentaires de [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/887/pourquoi-y-a-t-il-autant-de-voyelles-en-francais/908#908), nous avons parlé de la correction de cette phrase :

> **La transformation** qui a conduit le français à cette situation pourrait correspondre à **ce** qui est **expliqué** sur Wikipedia.

Après, j'ai demandé pourquoi on a utilisé *ce*, parce que ce mot concerne *la transformation*, qui est féminin. Pourquoi pas :

> **La transformation** qui a conduit le Français à cette situation pourrait correspondre à **celle** qui est **expliquée** sur Wikipedia.

La question est : peut-on utiliser indifféremment « ce qui » ou « celle qui » dans cette phrase ? Et pourquoi ?

Comment: Personnelement, je pense que l'équivalent masculin de "celle" n'est pas "ce" mais "celui".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Les deux phrases sont correctes. Elles ne suivent pas la même construction, mais elles ont ici des sens très voisins. La différence n'est pas liée à un accord de genre.

Dans « celle qui est expliquée », ***celle*** est un [pronom démonstratif](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronom_d%C3%A9monstratif#Syntaxe_du_pronom_.C2.AB_celui_.C2.BB) qui fait référence à un [**antécédent**](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant%C3%A9c%C3%A9dent_%28grammaire%29) féminin singulier qui apparaît un peu avant dans le texte, ici la transformation. On dirait ***celui*** pour un nom masculin singulier, et ***ceux*** ou ***celles*** au pluriel. Sans le pronom, la phrase serait « La transformation qui a conduit le français à cette situation pourrait correspondre à la transformation qui est expliquée sur Wikipedia ». En anglais, on traduirait « *the transformation … could correspond to the one that is explained on Wikipedia* ».

De manière générale, *celui qui* désigne un élément particulier dans une catégorie qui a été décrite précédemment. Le complément peut utiliser une autre conjonction (« celle que j'ai lue hier », « celle dont j'ai entendu parler hier », « celle avant laquelle la langue est désormais appelée ancien français », etc). Le complément peut aussi être un groupe nominal : « celle de l'article dont je parlais tout à l'heure », etc. Dans le [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/celui), voir le sens II.A.1 (et I.A.1 lorsque le complément est un nom).

Dans « ce qui est expliqué », ***ce*** est un [pronom démonstratif](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronom_d%C3%A9monstratif#Pronom_.C2.AB_ce_.C2.BB_suivi_d.27une_subordonn.C3.A9e) qui introduit une clause spécifiant l'objet. Le pronom est singulier et invariable en genre. Sans le pronom, on pourrait écrire « La transformation qui a conduit le français à cette situation pourrait correspondre au concept qui est expliqué sur Wikipedia » ou « ... à la chose qui est expliquée sur Wikipedia ». En anglais, on traduirait par « *the transformation … could correspond to what is explained on Wikipedia* ». Il n'y a **pas d'antécédent**, c'est le complément associé à *ce* qui détermine entièrement de quoi il est question. L'expression « ce qui est expliqué sur Wikipedia » peut donc être utilisée de manière autonome. Ici encore, le complément pourrait être introduit par une autre conjonction (« ce que j'ai lu hier sur Wikipedia », « ce dont nous avons parlé l'autre jour », etc) ; par contre un groupe nominal n'est pas possible dans ce sens du mot *ce*. Dans le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/c%27), voir l'entrée `c', ce¹`, sens I.B.

Le pronom ***ce*** est en quelque sorte de genre **neutre** qui désigne une notion ou une situation abstraite : s'il s'agit d'une personne ou d'un objet défini, on utilise *celui* (avec variation en genre et en nombre : *celle*, *ceux*, *celles*). Par exemple, « ce que j'ai vu » désigne une situation, un ensemble de choses ou un évènement. Par opposition, « celui/ceux que j'ai vu(s) » désigne soit des personnes soit des objets dont la nature fait partie du contexte de la discussion, et « celle/celles que j'ai vue(s) » désigne spécifiquement des femmes ou des objets dont le genre grammatical est féminin.

Comme souvent pour les pronoms, il existe d'autres constructions qui utilisent *ce* et *celui*. Je ne vois pas de meilleure manière de les détailler toutes que de lire un article de dictionnaire. La lecture de l'article concernant les **(pronoms) démonstratifs** dans une grammaire peut aussi apporter des précisions.

Comment: Version courte: _ce_ dans la phrase ne remplace pas _la transformation_; il n'a pas d'antécédent.

Comment: Merci @Gilles. Donc nous avons "celui/ceux", "celle/celles" et "ce/ceux"?

Comment: @Alenanno: Non, *ce* (dans ce sens-là) est singulier et invariable. Il y a un autre emploi de *ce*, comme déterminant (suivi d'un nom) qui est variable : *ce sens*, *cet emploi*, *cette utilisation*, *ces exemples* (*this meaning*, etc). *Ceux* est le pluriel de *celui*.

Comment: Ah, parfait. Donc, "celui/ceux", "celle/celles", "ce/cet/cette/ces"... :) très bien.

Comment: Gilles: je ne pense pas que les compléments de l'antécédent (adjectifs, subordonnées) soient transmis au pronom qui le référence. « Les billes qui sont rouges ne sont pas aussi belles que celles qui sont bleues. » est tout à fait acceptable.

Comment: Alenanno, je dirais « celui / ceux », « celle / celles », « ce » et « ce[t] *x* / cette *x* / ces *x* ».

Comment: @Stéphane Effectivement, l'envergure de l'antécédent n'est pas forcée par la grammaire, et c'est plus naturellement le nom seul qui est l'antécédent.