# What's the difference between "ce qui" and "ceux qui"

Tags: pronoms, démonstratifs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Peut-on utiliser « ce » dans cette phrase?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/915/peut-on-utiliser-ce-dans-cette-phrase)

How would one use “*ce qui*” differently as compared to “*ceux qui*”, “*celui qui*”, etc.?

Comment: Duplicate of http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/915/peut-on-utiliser-ce-dans-cette-phrase (in French); on how to handle such cross-language duplicates, see [this meta question](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/247/cross-language-duplicates-doublons-en-langues-differentes)

Answer (score 6):

« Ce » is only used for objects and sometimes for non-human living creatures (depends of the relation you have with it). It's a little bit like « it » in English. In fact, most of the times, if you would refer to something as « it », use « ce » instead of « celui », « celle », « ceux », ...

In your case, « ce qui » means « the thing that », but « ceux qui » means « those who ». It has a perfectly similar meaning, except that the subject is once « it » and once « they ».

Answer (score 4):

- *Ce qui* can refer to a previous part of the sentance or the text: in a certain way, you can compare *ce* to the english word *which* in that context:

> J'ai trouvé un travail, ce qui est bien.
> I have found a job, which is a good thing.

- *Ce qui* can also refer to something (but not somebody) for a future reference:

> Ce qui se trouve sur cette table me semble bon.

For somebody, we would use *celui qui (masc) / celle qui (fem) / ceux qui (plur)* instead:

> Ceux qui sont venus m'aider sont très gentils.
> Those who came to help me are very kind.

- We say *ce monsieur*, *ce plombier*, *cet agent*, *ce bureau*, *cette table*, etc, to refer to someone or something. We can then refer to it using *qui* by saying *celui/celle/ceux qui*, not *ce qui*:

> -Ce gars est sympathique. 
> -De qui parles-tu ?
> -Je parle de celui qui est assis sur la chaise, à côté de la table.
>
> -This guy is really nice. 
> -Who are you referring to?
> -I'm referring to the the guy sitting on the chair, close to the table.

Comment: Don't omit « ce qui se trouve sur la table », « what is on the table ».

Comment: That's absolutely right! I've edited my answer. Thanks Oltarus!