# When do we use "ce que" instead of "que"?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, subordonnées, pronoms-relatifs

I understand why it's “*ce que*” instead of “*que*” in this sentence:

> Ce n'est pas **ce que** j'ai commandé.

But I don't know the uses of “*ce que*”.

---

Je comprends pourquoi « *ce que* » est utilisé plutôt que « *que* » dans cette phrase :

> Ce n'est pas **ce que** j'ai commandé.

Mais je ne comprends pas comment utiliser, ou l'utilité, de « *ce que* ».

Comment: Does [this question](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/915/peut-on-utiliser-ce-dans-cette-phrase) or perhaps [its duplicate](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/whats-the-difference-between-ce-qui-and-ceux-qui) help?

Comment: @Gilles: Actually, it doesn't help me. I think it's a different question, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's a different question about the same grammatical construct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

La question porte sur le choix entre *ce que* ou *que* en tant que **pronom relatif**. *Que* a des usages très variés en français mais c'est le seul cas où on puisse hésiter entre les deux.

> Ce n'est pas ce que j'ai commandé.

*ce que* est ici un [pronom relatif](http://www.connectigramme.com/pronrel.htm/odyframe.htm) sans « référent » (appelé aussi « antécédent »). Il introduit la proposition relative complément d'objet (*Qu'est-ce que tu as commandé ?* → « ce que ») le pronom relatif remplace le nom qui le précède mais dans cette phrase il n'y a qu'un groupe verbal sans objet, on emploie « ce » pour représenter cet objet grammatical non nommé.

Si on avait un nom dans la proposition principale qui précède, on n'aurait pas besoin du *ce*, par exemple :

> Ce n'est pas le livre que j'ai commandé.

---

Your concern is about the use of *que* or *ce que* in a relative clause. Not to be confused with other uses of *que* in French (they are quite numerous).

> Ce n'est pas ce que j'ai commandé.

*ce que* is here a [relative pronoun](http://www.connectigramme.com/pronrel.htm/odyframe.htm) without an antedecent and it introduces a [relative clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subordinate_clause#Relative_.28adjectival.29_clause). It represents the object considered by the verb in the relative clause (*What did you order?* → “*ce que*”) the relative pronoun stands instead of the noun but in this kind of sentence  where *que* is only preceded by a verbal group without a grammatical object, *ce* is used  to represent the grammatical object and in a way plays the role of the noun.

If we had a noun in the clause preceding the *que*, we wouldn't use *ce*, for instance :

> Ce n'est pas le livre que j'ai commandé.

If you want to compare with English :

> Ce n'est pas **ce que** j'ai commandé → *It's not **what** I ordered.*

We must use some kind of antecedent in English (whether it be “the thing”, “what” or whatever).

> Ce n'est pas le livre **que** j'ai commandé → *It's not the book I ordered. / It's not the book **which**/**that** I ordered.*

In English we can use *that* or *which* or the relative pronoun *can be omitted* altogether.

Comment: Si, pour example, on m'emporte un livre au lieu de un chaier, je peut dire aussi "Ce n'est pas un livre ce que j'ai commandé"? Ou c'est miex "Ce n'est pas un livre que j'ai commandé" ?

Comment: @Paolo: Question intéressante. C'est plus usuel de dire « Ce n'est pas un livre que j'ai commandé (mais un cahier) ». Mais je peux imaginer une situation où on dirait  « ce n'est pas un livre ce que j'ai commandé (mais un cahier) » ce qui ne serait pas possible avec l'emploi de l'article défini **le** bien sûr.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a rigorous explanation, but when you can say **the thing that** in English, you have to say **ce que** in French. In proper English, it's most often translated by **what**.
For instance:

> Ce n'est pas ce que j'ai commandé. → *It's not the thing that I ordered.* → *It's not what I ordered.*
>
> Je mange ce que je veux. → *I eat the thing that I want.* → *I eat what I want.*

Basically **ce** is a pronoun, that can represent anything.

Answer (score 1):

My faint memories from grammar class tell me that in the sentence

> Ce n'est pas ce que j'ai commandé.

the *"que j'ai commandé"* part is a *relative clause* (someone please correct me if I am wrong), in French a *"proposition relative"*, and it needs to relate to an *object* which in this example is *"ce"* (itself referring to the first *"ce"*, the subject).

If you just say *"Ce n'est pas que j'ai commandé"*, you have a *subject* (*"Ce"*), a *verb* (*"n'est pas"*), a *relative clause* (*"que j'ai commandé"*), and… no *object* for it to relate to.

Maybe it will look more clear with a different example:

> Ce n'est pas **le plat** que j'ai commandé.

In this sentence *"ce"* and *"le plat"* are two different elements, which both refer to the same semantic matter, but have different roles in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Think of “*ce*” as “this”.

> Ce est tellement beau (*correction:* C'est tellement beau.)

Comment: In the example provided by the OP, *ce* is not used as a demonstrative.

Answer (score 0):

Its so easy ce refers to anything like it in English, so

It is not the book I ordered,

Ce n'est pas le livre que ...

It's not it that I ordered

Ce n'est pas ce que ...