# Why do we need "ce" in "Surtout ne t’attends pas à ce que je puisse te parler"?

Tags: sens, conjonctions

The question is on *ce que* as highlighted in this passage from chapter 5 of La porte étroite by André Gide.  The passage is from a letter by Alissa.

> Voici ma dernière lettre, mon ami. Si peu fixé que tu sois encore sur la date de ton retour, elle ne peut beaucoup tarder ; je ne pourrais plus rien t’écrire. C’est à Fongueusemare que j’aurais désiré te revoir, mais la saison est devenue mauvaise, il fait très froid et père ne parle plus que de rentrer en ville. À présent que Juliette ni Robert ne sont plus avec nous, nous pourrions aisément te loger, mais il vaut mieux que tu descendes chez tante Félicie, qui sera heureuse elle aussi de te recevoir.
>        
>   À mesure que le jour de notre revoir se rapproche, mon attente devient plus anxieuse ; c’est presque de l’appréhension ; ta venue tant souhaitée, il me semble, à présent, que je la redoute ; je m’efforce de n’y plus penser ; j’imagine ton coup de sonnette, ton pas dans l’escalier, et mon cœur cesse de battre ou me fait mal… Surtout ne t’attends pas à **ce que** je puisse te parler… Je sens s’achever là mon passé ; au-delà je ne vois rien ; ma vie s’arrête…

**QUESTION**

1. Does it mean *what* or *that*?
2. If it means *that* please explain the general principle by which it comes to mean *that* rather than, as it ordinarily does, *what*.  Maybe it would help if you gave other instances where one would have to use *ce que* to mean *that*.

**BACKGROUND**

All the translations I have tell me that, in the sentence, Alissa tells Jerome (letter's addressee) not to expect that she should be able to speak to him (which makes perfect sense in the context).  For example, by Dorothy Bussy:

> And whatever you do, don't expect me to be able to speak to you.

Meanwhile,the pattern I have seen with the reflexives is that they use a preposition to take a noun, but get rid of the preposition in favor of *que* to take a clause.  For example:

> - se persuader de [something]
> - se persuader que [a clause]

From this pattern, I might have expected:

> Surtout ne t’attends pas **que** je puisse te parler…

But instead, the book has retained *à* and added *ce*.

Without context, I would have read the result to mean:

> Above all, don't expect what I could say to you.

So I wonder, is there a (second) pattern of reflexives, by which "se + verb + preposition + *ce que*" has the same meaning as "se + verb + que" (i.e. the meaning of *that*)?  If so, what are some other instances?

Or maybe, the Gide sentence literally means *what I can say to you*, and the translators are extrapolating to suit the context?

Comment: Possibly dupolicate of [this other SE question](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1678/when-do-we-use-ce-que-instead-of-que).

Comment: @xenoid They're entirely different questions. Catomic's question is not on *ce que* only but why *ce que* after  *s'attendre à*.

Comment: @Alone-zee Thanks. I found this on *demander* (http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/demander): "[Le compl. d'obj. est une prop. complétive introduite par que, plus rarement par à ce que (fam.), dont le verbe est au subj.; le suj. de la complétive, gén. indéf., est différent de celui du verbe demander; l'éventuel compl. secondaire désigne le plus souvent une pers. différente de ces deux suj.] Je demande à ce qu'il soit sursis à l'audition d'autres témoins..."

Comment: Also http://www.wordreference.com/fren/%C3%A0%20ce%20que%20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translations are correct but your hunch of what it could have been in French is correct as well. Gide could have written his sentence:

> Surtout ne t’attends pas que je puisse te parler.

There's absolutely no difference in meaning between what Gide has written and what he could have written, the difference lies in what is considered a classical use and Gide's modern use. In the [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/attendre) (III 3) we can read that both *s'attendre que* and *s'attendre à ce que* are correct but that purists advocate the former and the latter is more usual.

The following explanation is from [Grevisse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Bon_Usage) I will expand beyond the scope of your question.

***S'attendre que***, pris affirmativement, se construit, selon l'usage classique, avec l'indicatif (souvent un temps du futur) ; mais, dans l'usage moderne, il se construit fréquemment aussi avec le subjonctif.

Indicatif:

> Vous devez bien vous attendre qu'on épluchera votre conduite. (Voltaire, *Au marq. de Villette*, 1<sup>er</sup> sept. 1765)

Subjonctif:

> Mr Gore (...) s'attend que vous lui fassiez une petite visite de gratitude. (J. Green, *L'Autre*)

***S'attendre que***, pris négativement ou interrogativement, demande le subjonctif dans la subordonnée :

> Elle ne s'attendait pas tout de même que pour des rêves de femme un magistrat aille risquer sa position (P. Claudel, *Figures et Paraboles*)

Grevisse has numerous examples but I have chosen Claudel's on purpose because he is a contemporary of Gide.

**S'attendre à ce que** entraîne  avec le subjonctif

> Elle s'attendait à ce qu'il lui ouvrît. (Colette, *Julie de Corneilhan*)

mais, ajoute Grevisse, on trouve parfois l'indicatif :

> Je m'attends à ce que dans huit jours il viendra me demander pardon.

Personnellement je trouve que l'indicatif sonne bizarre dans ce dernier cas, probablement par ce qu'il est peu usité.

---

<sup>Note: I have ignored your reflexion about reflexive verbs, I think it is not relevant here.</sup>

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me the section number in Grevisse?

Comment: @Catomic Dixième édition. § 999 ; section 7 (Chapitre sur les propositions substantives). Je n'ai pas accés à une édition plus récente. Voir aussi le TLF III 3. (Je viens d'ajouter un extrait à ma réopnse).

Answer (score 3):

*S'attendre* is a pronominal verb which, like *se préparer* is always followed by the preposition *à* when introducing a noun or a verb, e.g.:

- Je **m'attend à** la guerre.
- Je **me prépare à** la guerre.

Some pronominal verbs do not use a preposition before a noun, e.g. *se souhaiter*:

- Je **me souhaite** une bonne guerre

For some reason, when the pronominal verb *s'attendre* is followed by a clause, classical writers used to miss the ***à*** and directly append the clause.

- *Je **m'attend** qu'il y ait la guerre.* ?!

But this anomaly is not present with other verbs:

- *Je **me prépare à** ce qu'il y ait la guerre.* Correct
- *Je **me prépare** qu'il y ait la guerre.* Incorrect

Reciprocally:

- *Je **me souhaite à** ce qu'il y ait une bonne guerre.* Incorrect
- Je **me souhaite** qu'il y ait bonne une guerre. Correct

Nowadays, the dubious "classical" form has almost been eradicated by the regular one:

- *Je **m'attend à** ce qu'il y ait la guerre.*

[image]

I would recommend reading [this blog](http://alafortunedumot.blogs.lavoixdunord.fr/tag/s'attendre+que) about it.

Comment: Thank you.  The blog was critical information as I don't want to go around saying "je m'attend que" and being a *cuistre*!

Comment: One question on *Je **te** souhaite.* Did you perhaps mean *Je **me** souhaite*?  I suspect it because you were offering an example of a type of pronominal verb.

Comment: @Catomic You are right. That doesn't change the conclusions but I thought "se souhaiter à soi-même" was a little odd; answer edited anyway to correctly use a pronominal verb.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but an attempt to schematize the distinction for comprehension by me as a beginner level student.

I want to see *ce que* in the sense of *what* as consisting of a demonstrative pronoun and a relative pronoun, on the model of English *that which*.  For example:

> - C’est **ce que** me dit ma mère.
> - It's **what** mother tells me.
> - It's **that which** mother tells me.

But *ce que* in the sense of *that* would consist of a pronoun and a conjunction introducing a clause so that pronoun and clause are apposite.

> - Surtout ne t’attends pas à **ce que** je puisse te parler.
> - Above all, don't expect **it : that** I could talk to you.

Again I don't mean that this is correct grammatical analysis or what goes on in the head of a native speaker.  By them the expression is probably a single unit not subject to parsing.

If anyone comments on the scheme to tell me why it does not make sense even as a learning device, that too would be great.