# When to use "ce dont," "ce que," and "ce qui"

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs

I'm still very confused on the usage of these three  pronouns. *Ce dont*, *ce que*, et *ce qui* are for ideas not people. But I sometimes use *que*, *qui*, or *dont*.

I made some sentences to see if I am using them properly. Please give me feedback. Merci beaucoup.

1. J'ai reçu un e-mail du recruteur ce qui m'a informé qu'on veut passer un entretien d'embauche avec moi.
2. J'envisage ce que j'habiterai dehors du pays dans 10 ans.
3. Ce dont il a honte c'est ses échecs.

Comment: Partly related.  [When do we use “ce que” instead of “que”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1678/358).

Answer (score 9):

If you find word-by-word translations helpful, you can always remember that it's often possible to understand these parallel to how you use *qui*, *que*, and *dont* already. If *que* and *qui* mean "that/which", *ce que* and *ce qui* mean "the thing that/which". If *dont* means "of which", *ce dont* means "the thing of which".

Those don't sound very natural without context, though, so you might prefer this summary:

- *ce que* stands for the direct object of a verb. It's usually translated "what".
- *ce qui* stands for the subject of a verb. It's usually translated "what".
- *ce dont* stands for "*de*" + the object of a verb. It's usually translated "what ... of".
  (Wait a second for this to make sense.)

And unlike *que*, *qui*, and *dont*, all of the above could start a sentence when they fill the same role.

Let's try them out.

> **Ce qui** m'aide le plus, c'est pratiquer beaucoup.
>   
> ***What*** helps me the most is practicing a lot.
>   
> → Note that **ce qui** has replaced the subject of "help".
>
> **Ce que** j'aime le plus, c'est jouer du piano.
>   
> ***What*** I like the most is playing piano.
>   
> → Note that **ce que** has replaced the object of "like".
>
> **Ce dont** je suis fier, c'est que je n'abandonne pas.
>   
> ***What*** I'm proud **of** is that I don't give up.
>   
> → Note that **ce dont** has replaced the object of "am proud of".

Now that we've seen how they work, we can check your sentences.

> J'ai reçu un e-mail du recruteur **ce qui** m'a informé ...
>   
> *I received an email from the recruiter **what** informed me...*

"What" doesn't sound right here, and neither does "that which" (if you're ever unsure, try both). So we should just use *qui* "which".

> J'envisage **ce que** j'habiterai dehors du pays dans 10 ans.
>   
> *I envision **what** I'll live outside of the country in 10 years.*

"What" doesn't sound right here either, and neither does "that which". So we should just use *que* "that".

> **Ce dont** il a honte c'est ses échecs.
>   
> ***What*** he's ashamed **of** is his failures.

Yes, that sounds fine. Keep *ce dont* here!

Comment: Regarding *J'ai recu un e-mail du recruteur ce qui m'a informé...*, do I understand correctly that *qui* here relates to *recruteur* (as opposed to *e-mail*)? Or could it refer to both?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann If it were just "qui", I'd say it's technically ambiguous but probably cleaves closer to "recruteur" (not that the meaning is much different in this sentence). Now, what I neglected to mention is that you *could* put a comma after "recruteur" and then use "ce qui". Then it would refer to the email. If I get my head around why that is and when you can do it, I might edit this answer later.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I believe that is because in such a construction, *ce qui* is actually equivalent to *cela* instead of forming a cleft sentence  or leading a subordinate clause.