# Ceux qui/ceux que : « ceux » peut-il désigner autre chose que des personnes ?

Tags: pronoms, orthographe, démonstratifs

J'ai lu l'ensemble des questions et réponses (ici et sur d'autres forums) portant sur « ceux qui », mais je n'ai pas trouvé de réponse à ma question. 
Voici un exemple d'une réponse à la question posée [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/915/peut-on-utiliser-ce-dans-cette-phrase) (Note : la réponse a été modifiée depuis) :

> Le pronom ce est en quelque sorte de genre neutre : s'il s'agit d'une
>   personne, on utilise celui (avec variation en genre et en nombre). Par
>   exemple, « ce que j'ai vu » peut être « l'objet que j'ai vu » ou «
>   l'évènement que j'ai vu » ; « ceux que j'ai vus » désigne des
>   personnes, et « celles que j'ai vues » désigne spécifiquement des
>   femmes.

Cela sous-entend que « ceux » ne peut désigner que des personnes.

Comment écrire « ceux » dans cette phrase ?

> Les objectifs de cette association, surtout ceux qui concernent la
>   communication, ne sont pas très clairs.

Si je remplace « objectifs » par « missions » alors je dois utiliser « celles ».

> Les missions de cette association, surtout celles qui concernent la
>   communication, ne sont pas très claires.

Cela voudrait donc dire que « ceux/celles » pourrait aussi désigner des objets…

Comment: Celui/celle (pluriel ceux/celles) sont des pronoms démonstratifs qui peuvent remplacer aussi bien des objets que des personnes. Et d'ailleurs je comprends [la phrase que tu cites](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/915/peut-on-utiliser-ce-dans-cette-phrase) comment voulant dire que "ce" ne peut pas être mis pour une personne. Dans cette phrase citée dans cette même réponse  « celle que j'ai lue hier » désigne visiblement un objet ! Autre exemple que je viens de fabriquer « Quels paragraphes supprimer ? » « Ceux  que j'ai surlignés ».

Comment: Merci Laure ! C'est plus clair maintenant !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ceux](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/ceux/)

> Désigne des personnes ou **des choses** dont il est question dans la conversation.

*Ceux/Celles* peut aussi bien désigner des objets que des personnes.

Comment: Merci @Sifu, je comprend mieux maintenant!

Comment: @Arone Au plaisir!