# Qui qu'ils sont

Tags: oral

The excellent series [« Je voudrais qu'on m'efface »](https://ici.radio-canada.ca/tele/je-voudrais-qu-on-m-efface/site) has some behind-the-scenes videos, such as [« Du roman à la série »](https://ici.radio-canada.ca/tele/je-voudrais-qu-on-m-efface/site/videos/8396857/roman-a-serie), where one gets a sample of modern Montréalais French. (The series itself has been great for that too, but of course that's scripted and these videos are spontaneous.)

The director, Eric Piccolo, uses these structures:

> l'histoire est vraiment qui qu'ils sont

> tu as le goût de savoir comment qu'ils vont arriver à leurs fins

This structure would of course be censured by my traditional grammar. The subtitle transcriptionist has eliminated the extra *que*. But he says it with enough confidence that I don't think he's just stuttering. The fluency of his speech also suggests that he's a native speaker.

Is this common in Montréal / Québec? (Or elsewhere?) How normal and conversational vs. how broken does it sound?

Comment: « Les gens dans la rue : d’où qu’ils viennent ? Où qu’ils vont ? Qui qu’ils sont ? » Georges Perec *Espèces d'espaces*.  Français Perec (c.a.d pas Québécois)

Comment: Pas de réponse à donner, juste pour dire que ça peut s'entendre ici, ça fait très familier et n'est pas Perec qui veut. Mais c'est peut-être plus présent au Québec ? Pour info je viens de trouver cette phrase sur [La presse.ca](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/asie-oceanie/201211/18/01-4595164-obama-en-birmanie-pour-doper-les-reformes-politiques.php) dans la presse québécoise: « simplement pour ce qui qu'ils sont ou pour d'où ils viennent ».

Comment: Oui, _comment qu'ils vont arriver_ à leur fin se conçoit en France aussi, vieilli et dans un registre rural peut-être. _Qui qu'ils sont_ peut-être plus rare pour moi par contre (je sais que la question porte spécifiquement sur le contexte Québécois, pour lequel malheuresement je ne sais pas).

Comment: @Frank En revanche, s'il s'agit d'une tournure universelle et non juste du Québec, je serai content d'en apprendre plus sans préjugé géographique :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak Instinctivement, je dirais plutôt _quels qu'**ils** soient_, et je ne crois pas avoir jamais entendu _qui qu'ils sont_, pour ma part.

Comment: Chais pas qui qu'ils sont, mais comment qu'ils parlent !

Comment: It occurs to me that I've heard *où on est* distinguished from *où qu'on est* as a parallel to the distinction between "where one is" and "wher*ever* one is". Perhaps that strategy spread to the other complements?...

Comment: @LukeSawczak *Où on est* is usually "Where we are" or "Where are we" if the tone is interrogative. "Wherever one is" would rather be *où qu'on soit/où que l'on soit* which are regular while *où qu'on est* is very casual French like is *où s'qu'on est*.

Comment: @jlliagre Ah, OK, that's helpful. But mainly the addition of the 'que' is my focus there.

Comment: @LukeSawczak We're going to end up getting a slap on the wrist from a moderator if we keep talking like this in comments ;-)

Comment: @LukeSawczak In many cases in "standard French", those expressions would be perceived as older, regional or "less educated" - not saying that perception is correct, but it would likely be frowned upon by "more educated" folks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C'est Annie Cordy qui m'a mis sur la voie de cette réponse ([*Qui qu'en veut ? Qui qu'en veut  ? De mes crêpes aux œufs ?*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8sR7GYOPCYU)) : il faut aller voir du côté des interrogatives ! Et j'ai trouvé des pistes dans *La Grande grammaire du français* qui aborde le sujet dans le chapitre XII : *Les Phrases interrogatives*.
Bien que pouvant s'entendre aussi en France<sup>1</sup> ce *que* superfétatoire est plus une spécificité Québécoise.

<sup>J'ai fait une copie sélective d'éléments en rapport avec la question, je n'ai pas recopié les exemples sauf exceptions. Pour ce qui est des exemples provenant du [*Corpus de français parlé au Québec*](https://applis.flsh.usherbrooke.ca/cfpq/index.php/site/afficher/corpusmulti) (*CFPQ*), j'ai fait un hyperlien vers la recherche directe dans le corpus. J'ai peut-être au passage oublié d'indiquer les endroits où j'ai effectué des coupures dans le texte de la GGF.</sup>

> **3.5.2 La variation dans les interrogatives partielles indépendantes**
> [...]
> **Les interrogatives partielles avec *est-ce que, c'est que* et *que***
> […]
> Les formes *c'est que*, *c'est qui* peuvent remplacer *est-ce que* après un mot interrogatif extrait, en registre informel. Au Québec, *c'est que* est souvent abrégé en *ce que*.
>
> - *Qui c'est qui commande ici ?*
> - *[...] quand c'est que tu nous emmènes sur la lune ?* (D. Pennac, 1989)
> - *Comment c'qu'y va, Bobby ?* (M. Tremblay)
>
> **Les interrogatives introduites par mot interrogatif + *que***
> Les interrogatives partielles introduites par un constituant interrogatif directement suivi de *que* sont largement attestées au Québec. Ainsi le *Corpus de français parlé au Québec* (*CFPQ*) en compte un nombre non négligeable. [...]. Par ordre d'importance on trouve [*pourquoi*](https://applis.flsh.usherbrooke.ca/cfpq/index.php/transcriptions/recherche/mot?typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=pourquoi%20que&yt0=CHERCHER) et dans une moindre mesure, [*où*](https://applis.flsh.usherbrooke.ca/cfpq/index.php/transcriptions/recherche/mot?typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=o%C3%B9%20c%27est%20que&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=o%C3%B9%20&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=o%C3%B9%20est-ce%20que&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=o%C3%B9%20c%27que&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=ousque&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=o%C3%B9%20est-ce%20que&yt0=CHERCHER), pour lequel prévaut la forme *où c'que*, parfois orthographié *ousque*.
>
> - ! *Pourquoi que ça a été encouragé de de donner le biberon*.
> - ! *Ousque j'irai une fois divorcé*.
>
> La séquence [*quand que*](https://applis.flsh.usherbrooke.ca/cfpq/index.php/transcriptions/recherche/mot?typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=o%C3%B9%20c%27est%20que&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=o%C3%B9%20&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=o%C3%B9%20est-ce%20que&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=o%C3%B9%20c%27que&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=ousque&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=o%C3%B9%20est-ce%20que&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=quand%20que&yt0=CHERCHER), éventuellement précédée d'une préposition, est employée au Canada de même que [*comment que*](https://applis.flsh.usherbrooke.ca/cfpq/index.php/transcriptions/recherche/mot?typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=o%C3%B9%20c%27est%20que&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=o%C3%B9%20&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=o%C3%B9%20est-ce%20que&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=o%C3%B9%20c%27que&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=ousque&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=o%C3%B9%20est-ce%20que&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=quand%20que&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=comment%20que&yt0=CHERCHER).
>
> Enfin les séquences [*qui que*](https://applis.flsh.usherbrooke.ca/cfpq/index.php/transcriptions/recherche/mot?typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=o%C3%B9%20c%27est%20que&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=o%C3%B9%20&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=o%C3%B9%20est-ce%20que&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=o%C3%B9%20c%27que&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=ousque&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=o%C3%B9%20est-ce%20que&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=quand%20que&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=comment%20que&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=qui%20que&yt0=CHERCHER) ou [*qui qui*](https://applis.flsh.usherbrooke.ca/cfpq/index.php/transcriptions/recherche/mot?typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=o%C3%B9%20c%27est%20que&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=o%C3%B9%20&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=o%C3%B9%20est-ce%20que&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=o%C3%B9%20c%27que&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=ousque&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=o%C3%B9%20est-ce%20que&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=quand%20que&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=comment%20que&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=qui%20que&yt0=CHERCHER&typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=qui%20qui&yt0=CHERCHER) (que le pronom corresponde à un sujet ou à un complément) sont possibles mais très rares.
>
> - *Qui que tu as vu ?*
>
> En France, cette construction se rencontre peu à l'écrit, hors emploi ludique ou citation. Bien qu'elle soit stigmatisée par la norme, on la trouve à l'oral : de façon non négligeable dans le [*Corpus ESLO*](http://eslo.huma-num.fr/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1) d'Orléans, avec des locuteurs de catégories socioprofessionnelles diverses, ou dans le [corpus de *Phonologie du français contemporain*](https://www.projet-pfc.net/) pour différentes régions. Comme au Québec, *comment que* et *pourquoi que* y sont plus représentés que *où que*, par exemple ; préposition + *qui que* et *quand que* sont totalement absents.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> *Les gens dans la rue : d’où qu’ils viennent ? Où qu’ils vont ? Qui qu’ils sont* ?  Georges Perec *Espèces d'espaces*</sup>

Comment: Certaines des ces tournures s'entendent aussi en France: _Qui c'est qui commande ici ?_, _quand c'est que tu nous emmènes sur la lune ?_, _Pourquoi que ça a été encouragé de de donner le biberon._ sont tout à fait possibles en France ... mais pas à l'école :-)

Comment: @Frank Oui, c'est bien ce que dit le dernier  § recopié de la GGF. On doit en trouver dans le corpus citer. Quelques exemples cités sont d'ailleurs d'auteurs ou de locuteurs francophones : Qui c'est qui commande ici ?
[...] quand c'est que tu nous emmènes sur la lune ? (D. Pennac, 1989)

Comment: Un mot clef pour briller dans les salons: *percontatives* ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre waouh!

Comment: Moi je préfère _wesh_ qui est dans le Robert maintenant et qui est très pratique au Scrabble ;-) _wesh_ peut être percontatif aussi, en vrai ;-)

Comment: @Frank Probablement une question de génération, mais je comprends wesh même si je ne l'utilise pas.

Comment: @None Je ne fais que m'amuser à imiter, mais je connais pas mal de jeunes dont le français diverge de plus en plus de ce que j'ai appris.

Comment: Further evidence for this answer: at around 0:35 in [this video](https://ici.radio-canada.ca/tele/je-voudrais-qu-on-m-efface/site/videos/8397400/tournage-au-garage), the speaker says "La scène où ce que Meg a appris ..." (again not captured in the subtitles).

Comment: @LukeSawczak Can't access this video in France but at first sight this is a different sentence structure, this is *ce que* and  *La scène où ce que Meg a appris* is valid (the scene in which Meg learnt ...) [Here](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1686/358) and [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/917/358)

Comment: @None I don't think it's one of those cases — I should've quoted more because I see the ambiguity in the fragment I quoted. It goes: « où ce que Meg a appris que ses enfants ont été abandonnés par son chum ». Also, he does pronounce it *oùsque* with a pause afterwards, as though *où* were replaced wholesale by *oùsque*, as each of these question pronouns seems to be functionally doing.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I can't tell without hearing more of the conversation (I I just noticed I missed a word in my translation, meant "the scene in which what Meg learnt...).

Comment: @None Precisely — my fragment was misleading in that it could easily have been the direct object *ce que* rather than the one under discussion here. But the full sentence makes clear that it isn't, and is more in line with his *qui* and *comment*.